# flex not wokring in html css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The div with className `Offer__Sidebar` contains all the 5 elements which are shown in the image above. The "Offer__Sidebar" is used for sidebar and I want that the sidebar should occupy only 20% of the total horizontal space. Therefore, I have applied flex: 0.2, but it's not working.

[image]

***HTML CODE***

```
            <div className="Section">
                <div className="Offers">
                    <div className="Offer__Sidebar">
                        <div className="Offers_Near_You">
                            <img
                                className="Offer__img"
                                src={offersNearYou} />
                            <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
                                <div>Offers Near You</div>
                                <p>211 OPTIONS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="Top_Picks">
                            <img
                                className="Offer__img"
                                src={topPicks} />
                            <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
                                <div>Top Picks</div>
                                <p>58 OPTIONS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="Whats_New">
                            <img
                                className="Offer__img"
                                src={whatsNew} />
                            <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
                                <div>What's New</div>
                                <p>32 OPTIONS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="Vegeterian_Options">
                            <img
                                className="Offer__img"
                                src={vegeterianOption} />
                            <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
                                <div>Vegeterian Options</div>
                                <p>455 OPTIONS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="See_All">
                            <img
                                className="Offer__img"
                                src={seeAll} />
                            <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
                                <div>SEE ALL</div>
                                <p>866 OPTIONS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="Offer__Restuarants">
               
                </div>
         </div>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
.Section{
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;    
}

.Offer__Sidebar{
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid red;
    flex: 0.2;
    
}
.Offers_Near_You, .Top_Picks, .Whats_New, .Vegeterian_Options, .See_All{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    
}

/* hover effect */
.Offers_Near_You:hover img { 
    background: orangered;
}
.Offer__div{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.Offer__div div{
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #3d4152;
}

.Offer__div p{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 4px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: #282c3f;
}

.Offer__img{
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    
}

#a1:hover~a2{
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid here. This should do what you want.

.Offer__Sidebar => 20%

sibling element => all remaining space

```css
.Offers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
}

.Offer__Sidebar {
  flex: 0.2; /*Remove this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your markup is set up correctly to support what you're trying to do, because your `flex` element has no flex container.

`Offer__Sidebar` is a child of `Offer`, and `Offer` has no styles applied to it, so it does not `display: flex`. Since `Offer__Sidebar` doesn't have a `display: flex` parent the `flex` declaration will have no effect.

[Docs example of a flex container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#setting_flex_auto)

Your code updated:

```css
.Section {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.Offers {
  display: flex;
}

.Offer__Sidebar {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex: 20%;
  flex-shrink: 2;
}
.Offer__OtherThing {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  flex: 80%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.Offers_Near_You,
.Top_Picks,
.Whats_New,
.Vegeterian_Options,
.See_All {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.Offer__Restuarants {
  border: 1px green solid;
}


/* hover effect */

.Offers_Near_You:hover img {
  background: orange;
}

.Offer__div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.Offer__div div {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #3d4152;
}

.Offer__div p {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 4px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #282c3f;
}

.Offer__img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
}

#a1:hover~a2 {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Section">
  <div class="Offers">
    <div class="Offer__Sidebar">
      <div class="Offers_Near_You">
        <img class="Offer__img" src={offersNearYou} />
        <div id="a1" class="Offer__div">
          <div>Offers Near You</div>
          <p>211 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Top_Picks">
        <img class="Offer__img" src={topPicks} />
        <div id="a1" class="Offer__div">
          <div>Top Picks</div>
          <p>58 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Whats_New">
        <img class="Offer__img" src={whatsNew} />
        <div id="a1" class="Offer__div">
          <div>What's New</div>
          <p>32 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Vegeterian_Options">
        <img class="Offer__img" src={vegeterianOption} />
        <div id="a1" className="Offer__div">
          <div>VegeterianclassOptions VegeterianclassOptions VegeterianclassOptions VegeterianclassOptions VegeterianclassOptions VegeterianclassOptions</div>
          <p>455 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="See_All">
        <img class="Offer__img" src={seeAll} />
        <div id="a1" class="Offer__div">
          <div>SEE ALL</div>
          <p>866 OPTIONS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Offer__OtherThing">
      I'm not sure what's suppoed to go here? How big do you want this?
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="Offer__Restuarants">
    Other...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That `flex` atribute does't work this way.

`flex` is an abbreviation for three flex atributes: flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis.

To achieve the what you want you need to change the `flex: 0.2` to `width: 20%` and add `flex: 1` into `.Offer__Restuarants`. This will make the `Offer__Sidebar` occupies 20% of the width and the rest of the content will be used be the `.Offer__Restuarants`. The `.Offers` needs to be `display: flex`.

Comment: Not necessarily true, a single value can be used to set the `flex-basis` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#syntax - although I agree that setting a `width` is more likely what's called for here.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, you are right